# DBIx::something that can restore session variables on reconnection?

Tags: perl, dbi

Ordinary DBI::db handler will lost all database session settings that was made using $dbh->do('SET variable_name=value').

Is there any DBIx::* class/package or so that provides method like "set_session" to set session variables and can restore this variables after detection of connection lost (connection timeout in 90% of real cases) ?

It may looks like this:

```
# inside the user code:
$dbh->set(variable => 'string', yet_another_variable => 42)

# inside the DBIx::* package:
sub reconnect {
# ...
  while (my ($var, $val) = each %{$self->saved_vars}) {
    $self->dbh->do("SET $var=?", {}, $val)
  }
# ...
}
```

Comment: It is recommended to use a connection manager like [DBIx::Connector](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Connector) or something from the [Mojo::Pg](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Pg) family as it will reconnect when needed and when forked - you can share the connector object without worry, and retrieve handles when needed. When using these you can use the same DBI callbacks or the [connection event](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Pg#connection) to set up each new connection.

Comment: @Grinnz , what about using DBIx::SQLEngine instead of DBIx::Connector. It seems, the reconnection implemented in DBIx::SQLEngine too, but it is simpler to use than Connector

Comment: It looks a lot more complicated to me, and quite a bit older. If you want an ORM that can also serve as the connection manager, the ideal choice is [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DBI supports [something called *Callbacks*](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Callbacks). I can't link to this bit of the doc as the section is quite long, so here it is verbatim.

> A more common application for callbacks is setting connection state
>   only when a new connection is made (by connect() or connect_cached()).
>   Adding a callback to the connected method (when using connect) or via
>   connect_cached.connected (when useing connect_cached()>) makes this
>   easy. The connected() method is a no-op by default (unless you
>   subclass the DBI and change it). The DBI calls it to indicate that a
>   new connection has been made and the connection attributes have all
>   been set. You can give it a bit of added functionality by applying a
>   callback to it. For example, to make sure that MySQL understands your
>   application's ANSI-compliant SQL, set it up like so:
>
> ```
> my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $auth, {
>     Callbacks => {
>         connected => sub {
>             shift->do(q{
>                 SET SESSION sql_mode='ansi,strict_trans_tables,no_auto_value_on_zero';
>             });
>             return;
>         },
>     }
> });
> ```

This is your exact use-case I believe. Do this instead of running your own code after you've connected.

Comment: Thank you! It is wonderful: no need to use some additional package in the stack, it's enough to hook DBI "connected" callback!